# Help with a simple problem involving a functional inequality (trying to prove Gronwall's inequality)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration, inequality

So while trying to prove Grownwall's inequality, my proof led me to the following statement: $h'(x) \le h(x)g(x)$.

Now when $h'(x)=h(x)g(x)$ the following holds: $h(x)=k \exp G(x)$, where $k$ is a constant number. Can I conclude from this that $h(x) \le k \exp G(x)$ (since $h'(x)<h(x)g(x)$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\frac{h'(t)}{h(t)}\le g(t).$$ Now integrate from $a$ to $x$.

Comment: Sure thing. Keep learning!

Answer (score 1):

Ted Shifrin's answer makes the classical mistake of assuming that $h>0$ uniformly - or else one cannot divide by $h$ without changing the inequality's direction. A correct version of the proof would be to work with the exponential:

$$
\begin{array}{clr}
& h'(x) \le h(x) g(x)\\
\Rightarrow & h'(x) - h(x) g(x) \le 0\\
\Rightarrow & {\rm exp}\left(\int_a^x g(s) ds\right) h'(x) - {\rm exp}\left(\int_a^x g(s) ds\right) h(x) g(x) \le 0 & \mbox{[since ${\rm exp}>0$]} \\
\Rightarrow & \left( {\rm exp}\left(\int_a^x g(s) ds\right) h(x) \right)'\le 0 & \mbox{[product rule]} \\
\Rightarrow & {\rm exp}\left(\int_a^x g(s) ds\right) h(x) \le h(a) & \mbox{[monotonicity of the integral]}\\
\Rightarrow & h(x) \le h(a) {\rm exp}\left(-\int_a^x g(s) ds\right) . & \mbox{[again since ${\rm exp}>0$]}
\end{array}
$$